# Amazon SNS for webhook to client (HTTP)

Tags: amazon-web-services, webhooks, amazon-sns

I am building a service through AWS and I can't figure it out how to send webhook to my clients through http(s).

It seems like one solution would be to create an SNS topic for everyone of them, then subscribe their URL to this topic, but I keep thinking this is an overkill solution.. I mean, one topic with one URL for each client..

Is there a solution with SNS that would allow me to send messages directly to an URL with HTTP ? Without having to create a topic for each of the clients then subscribe their url to that topic ?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely don't need one topic per subscriber. You can use one topic and subscribe all your client HTTP endpoints to it. Not only that, you can use multiple delivery protocols in the same topic, HTTP/HTTPS, email, ... which means that you can send the same message to multiple endpoints, each using the same or a different protocol at the same.

In AWS console, go to `SNS` -> `Topics` -> `Create Topic` and create a topic. Then go to `SNS` -> `Subscriptions` and create a subscription (you will need to specify your topic's arn, protocol to use and the endpoint address). You will need to create one subscription per endpoint. Once you are done, go to `SNS` -> `Topics` -> select the topic that you have created before. You will see all the subscriptions under `Subscriptions` tab which is opened by default.

Or you can use [aws sns cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/subscribe.html) to create those subscriptions.

```
aws sns subscribe
--topic-arn <value>
--protocol <value>
[--notification-endpoint <value>]
```

And to list the subscriptions by topic:

```
aws sns list-subscriptions-by-topic
--topic-arn <value>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry I probably mispoke. I meant sent a different message to each of the subscriber. I was hoping there was a way to send to an HTTP endpoint without creating a topic, but I feel like I'll have no other choice

Comment: You can still create a single topic and use `subscription filter policy` to filter out who will receive which message (based on keys, you can even create one-to-one mapping between message and a recipient while still having a single topic with all the subscriptions)

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it !